# Como traduzir um plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Olá, boa tarde!

Estou com um problema e não consigo encontrar a solução, estou usando o plugin Magic Members e estou tentando traduzir o plugin, pois esta em inglês, usei o plugin loco translate para traduzir, porém o campo que eu necessito não esta traduzindo, suspeito que essa variável está direto no código, abri o código e até localizei onde traduzir, só que quando subo o arquivo isso faz meu site dar aquela tela branca, alguém já passou por isso? podem me ajudar?

Comment: Não consta erro no log referente a esse plugin, simplesmente ele exibe a pagina toda em branca em qualquer alteração que for feita nos scripts do plugin. acredito que deva ter a ver com relação a pirataria

Comment: Até o momento ainda não consegui e não retorna erro.